# XSLT 3.0 Convert String data type to Date type and apply translate to remove characters

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Here is my source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Compensation>
    <Salary>
        <BasePay>$18600.1299</BasePay>
        <PayDate>15-Mar-2022</PayDate>
        <Bonus>$3500.99</Bonus>
        <Gym>$670</Gym>
        <Tax>$30,000.9912</Tax>
        
    </Salary>
    <Salary>
        <BasePay>$28600.12</BasePay>
        <PayDate>15-Mar-2022</PayDate>
        <Bonus>$1500.99</Bonus>
        <Gym/>
        <Tax>$50,000</Tax>        
    </Salary> 
</Compensation>
```

I am trying do following on my XML document

1. Format date to `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Currently date on my source XML is of `string` data type
2. Remove all currency and commas from whole document.

Here is my XSLT 3.0 solution which is working fine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs this"
        version="3.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        
        <xsl:function name="this:fromatDate" as="xs:string">            
            <xsl:param name="dateString"/>              
            <xsl:variable name="month"
                select="('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="dd" select="substring($dateString,1,2)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="mm"
                select="format-number(index-of($month,substring($dateString,4,3)),'00')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="yy" select="substring($dateString,8,4)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date( string-join(($yy, $mm, $dd), '-')),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
        </xsl:function>
        
        <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>      
        
              
       <!-- Removes $ symbol and commas --> 

        <xsl:template match="text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'$,', '')"/>
        </xsl:template> 

<!-- Convert string to date --> 
        
        <xsl:template match="PayDate">
            <FormattedPayDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="this:fromatDate(.)"/>
            </FormattedPayDate>
        </xsl:template>
        
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting the expected result as below. However, I'd like to use anyone's help to know if there is any efficient way to write this code since I want to use XSLT 3.0.

I'm not sure if there is any functions in xpath 3.0 to handle string conversions to date and character removal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Compensation>
   <Salary>
      <BasePay>18600.1299</BasePay>
      <FormattedPayDate>2022-03-15</FormattedPayDate>
      <Bonus>3500.99</Bonus>
      <Gym>670</Gym>
      <Tax>30000.9912</Tax>
   </Salary>
   <Salary>
      <BasePay>28600.12</BasePay>
      <FormattedPayDate>2022-03-15</FormattedPayDate>
      <Bonus>1500.99</Bonus>
      <Gym/>
      <Tax>50000</Tax>
   </Salary>
</Compensation>
```

Comment: If you know the name(s) of the elements where you want to call your function to format the date I don't understand why you would want to mix a function combining date formatting with the translation you need for monetary values. What would be the advantage?

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I was not looking for one function who does both. Function is expected to perform only date formatting not translation and date formatting. My idea was to use translation just to remove the characters such as currency symbol, comma etc.. to make the document clean for further processing. And for the dates, there is a several elements that would need to be formatted to YYYY-MM-DD. I thought this was a good approach and was looking to see if there is a more efficient way to do what i'm trying to do.

Comment: In terms of efficiency, Michael Kay usually points out that the proper way to have a function in XSLT 2/3 return a string is e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="format-date(xs:date( string-join(($yy, $mm, $dd), '-')),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>` and not `<xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date( string-join(($yy, $mm, $dd), '-')),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>` as that creates a text node (your `as="xs:string"` will convert it back to a string but that is usually inefficient).